# C++ template typename iterator

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

Consider the following header file:

```
template <typename T> struct tNode
{
    T Data;                      //the data contained within this node
    list<tNode<T>*> SubNodes;       //a list of tNodes pointers under this tNode

    tNode(const T& theData)
    //PRE:  theData is initialized
    //POST: this->data == theData and this->SubNodes have an initial capacity
    //      equal to INIT_CAPACITY, it is set to the head of SubNodes
    {
        this->Data = theData;
        SubNodes(INIT_CAPACITY);   //INIT_CAPACITY is 10
    }

};
```

Now consider a line of code from another file:

```
list<tNode<T>*>::iterator it();  //iterate through the SubNodes
```

The compiler is giving me this error message: `Tree.h:38:17: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<tNode<T>*>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<tNode<T>*>’ is a dependent scope`

I have no idea why the compiler is yelling at me for this.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In `list<tNode<T>*>::iterator`, you have a *dependant name*, that is, a name that depends on a template parameter.

As such, the compiler can't inspect `list<tNode<T>*>` (it doesn't have its definition at this point) and so it doesn't know whether `list<tNode<T>*>::iterator` is either a static field or a type.

In such a situation, the compiler assumes that it is a field, so in your case it yields a syntax error. To solve the issue, just tell the compiler that it is a type by putting a `typename` ahead of the declaration:

```
typename list<tNode<T>*>::iterator it
```

Answer (score 26):

Firstly, as other answers already noted, type names nested into dependent types need to be prepended with the `typename` keyword.

That keyword is not needed when the template is fully specialized, meaning that `list<tnode<int>*>::iterator` does not need `typename`, but when the outer class still depends on template parameter `T`, `typename` must be present.

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
  list<tnode<int>*>::iterator it1; // OK without typename
  typename list<tnode<T>*>::iterator it2; // typename necessary
}
```

Secondly, even with `typename` the

```
typename list<tNode<T>*>::iterator it();
```

declaration will declare a function, not an iterator. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 6):

`list<tNode<T>*>::iterator` is a dependant name, a type that depends on a template parameter. In order to declare that variable, you need to use the `typename` keyword:

```
typename list<tNode<T>*>::iterator it = ...;
```

Answer (score 3):

More backround on the answers above is provided here

[A Description of the C++ typename keyword](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html)

I had a different but similar problem in that I wanted to typedef an iterator for child nodes with the :

```
typedef std::vector<NodeType*>::iterator ChildIterator;
```

which gave me the same compiler error. With the suggestions here and help of the above link, the solution to my problem is to use

```
typedef typename std::vector<NodeType*>::iterator ChildIterator;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

## iterator can be a nested class and a class attribute

The ambiguity the `typename` keyword resolves is, that `T::iterator` (or in your case `list<tNode<T>*>::iterator`) can refer either to a `nested type` (case 1) or a `static class attribute` (case 2).
The compiler interprets a construction like this as case 2 by default. The `typename` keyword enforces case 1.

The following example, demonstrates an implementation each for case 1 and case 2. In both cases the line `T::iterator * iter;` appears. In case 1 it is only valid with the `typename` argument prepended. In case 2 it represent just a double (without any operation). The asteric * is just added, as it is in case 1 an indicator for a pointer and in case 2 the multiplication operator.

**minimal reproducible example**

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void foo1() {
    typename T::iterator * iter;
    std::cout << "foo1: iter points to: " << iter << std::endl;
}

class class1 {
    public:
        class iterator // subclass
        {
        };
};

template <class T>
void foo2() {
    double iter = 2.;
    T::iterator * iter;
    std::cout << "foo2: \"T::iterator * iter\" is a simple double: " << T::iterator * iter << std::endl;
}

class class2 {
    public:
        constexpr static double iterator = 11.;
};

int main()
{
    foo1<class1>();
    foo2<class2>();
    // foo1<class2>(); // does not compile
    // foo2<class1>(); // does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
foo1: iter points to: 0x4010b0
foo2: "T::iterator * iter" is a simple double: 22
```

Credits to [trueter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29029599/7128154) for pointing out the article [A Description of the C++ typename keyword](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edriscoll/typename.html). This answer is basically a short wrap up.