# Errors porting Win code to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, porting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)
>   [declaring a C++ set iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304492/declaring-a-c-set-iterator)

I'm trying to compile C++ some code, which works fine in Windows, in a Linux System.

I have got many errors like the following one:

```
code:
..
39          set<Node<T>*>::iterator child;
...
```

`g++` gives me the error:

```
Node.h:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘child’
```

This is just an example. Can you give me some hint on how to solve it?

Comment: it could be an encoding or windows linebreaks problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write

```
typename set<Node<T>*>::iterator child;
```

Indeed, the compiler does not know that `iterator` is the name of a `type` defined in the *templated* class `set`. You have to tell it explicitely.

Visual Studio allows this to be implicit. `gcc` does not.