# typedef vector template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, typedef

I'm trying to add some typedef to my class, but the compiler reports a syntax erron on the following code:

```
    template<class T>
    class MyClass{
        typedef std::vector<T> storageType; //this is fine
        typedef storageType::iterator iterator; //the error is here
```

but the next does not work too:

```
        typedef std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
```

I was looking for the answers on many forum but i can't find a solution or workaround for this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `typename`:

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
```

There are a lot of similar question. E.g. take a look at the following:

- [C++ template typename iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275444/c-template-typename-iterator)

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a dependent type so you need to add typename before it.

```
typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
        ^
```

Comment: Why doesn't he need it for the first one?

Comment: `std::vector<T>` isn't a dependent type. It's type can be determined without instantiating any templates. To determine the type of `std::vector<T>::iterator` you have to instantiate `std::vector<T>`.