# Template object passed as a parameter to another template object

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ template typename iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275444/c-template-typename-iterator)

Consider such code:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
     typedef std::map< int, boost::shared_ptr<T> > TMap;
     TMap myMap;

     void test()
     {
         TMap::const_iterator iter = myMap.begin(); // line 12
     }
};
```

After normal compilation with `g++ main.cpp` following lines are returned:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Test<T>::test()’:
main.cpp:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iter’
```

If I change `std::map< int, boost::shared_ptr<T> >` to `std::map< int, int >`, then it compiles.

It seems that there is a problem with template object `boost::shared_ptr<T>` passed as a parameter to another template object.

1. **Why?**
2. **How to fix this?**

Comment: Try this `typename TMap::const_iterator iter = myMap.begin();`