# Cannot pass template argument to std::list<T>::iterator

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, iterator

I made a container template class as follow:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class hash_table {
 public:
  class iterator {
   private:
    list<V> list_;                 // Works well
    list<V>::iterator it_;         // Fails: Syntax-error "iterator"
    list<int>::iterator it2_;      // Works well
  };
//....
}
```

Can someone tell me, what I did wrong at `list<V>::iterator it_;`? Why should this be an syntax error?

Comment: Try `typename list<V>::iterator it_;`.

Comment: See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

As @songyuanyao sugested, the solution is to put `typename` before the `list<V>::iterator` like in:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class hash_table {
 public:
  class iterator {
   private:
    list<V> list_;                 // Works well
    typename list<V>::iterator it_;         // No more fails
    list<int>::iterator it2_;      // Works well
  };
//....
}
```

See also:
[C++ template typename iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275444/c-template-typename-iterator)